# escaping " symbol used in findstr within a FOR statement

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Yeah, I've tried the most popular available solutions[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262364/escaping-quotes-in-findstr)[(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982802/escaping-a-quote-in-findstr-search-string)

They didn't help much; just restated what I already knew.

This works:

```
@echo on
set var=APPENDTEXT
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.* /b /a-d') do ren "%%a" "%%~na%var%%%~xa"
pause
```

but then I try to refine it a bit like so

```
@echo on
set var=APPENDTEXT
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.* /b /a-d | findstr /v /i "\.bat$" ') do ren "%%a" "%%~na%var%%%~xa"
pause
```

so that I do not end up renaming the batch file itself. **But then everything got messed up.**

I've tried several [approaches for escaping](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php), none working quite like I want them to.

> **Additional Information:** 
> *From what I gather, escaping " inside findstr is a problem when it is itself inside something else. I've*
>   *tried escaping with "" and with /" and with ^" to no avail. 
>
> Am I doing*
>   *something wrong in these approaches?*
>
> 1. ('dir *.* /b /a-d | findstr /v /i "".bat$"" ')
> 2. ('dir *.* /b /a-d | findstr /v /i \".bat$\" ')
> 3. ('dir *.* /b /a-d | findstr /v /i ^".bat$^" ')
>
> *What is the correct way to escape it?*
>   *

### What I want it to do ?

Simply put,

> When I run this.bat file inside a folder, I want all the files inside
>   it to be renamed with a APPENDTEXT (except the bat file itself) 
> Example:
>   a.dat --> aAPPENDTEXT.dat 
> pleasework.txt --> pleaseworkAPPENDTEXT.txt

Comment: You need to escape the PIPE.

Comment: You could also get rid of the findstr and just do a comparison to the file extension before the rename. `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.* /b /a-d') do IF /I NOT "%%~xa"==".bat" ren "%%a" "%%~na%var%%%~xa"`

Comment: You could also get rid of the comparision by locking the batch file `<"%~f0" 2>nul (for %%a in (*) do ren "%%a" "%%~na%var%%%~xa")`

Comment: In addition to the above, to satisfy your requirements why are you simply excluding the extension, use the **`^|FindStr/VIXC:"%~nx0"`**.

Comment: I suggest to use the command line `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir * /b /a-d') do if /i not "%~nx0" == "%%~nxa" ren "%%a" "%%~na%var%%%~xa"` to ignore the batch file running this command line.

Comment: There is no need to escape any `"` characters, unless you want them to be part of the search string...

Comment: @Squashman : interesting solution. How would I go on about improving the condition to exclude all files that already have APPENDTEXT in the end of their filenames.

what should I change here?  
`for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.* /b /a-d ^| findstr /v /i "\.bat$"') ren "%%a" "%%~na%var%%%~xa"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have escaped the `findstr` statement correctly, but the pipe `|` symbol still needs to be escaped.
 `| findstr`   →    `^| findstr`

```
@echo on
set var=APPENDTEXT
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.* /b /a-d ^| findstr /v /i "\.bat$" ') do ren "%%a" "%%~na%var%%%~xa"
pause
```

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: How would I go on about improving the condition to exclude all files that already have APPENDTEXT in the end of their filenames. what should I change here? `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.* /b /a-d ^| findstr /v /i "\.bat$"') do ren "%%a" "%%~na%var%%%~xa"` I've tried adding a findstr condition to check for "APPENDTEXT" in %%a right after `do` but it failed. Can you help me there?

Comment: @SiddhantRimal `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.* /b /a-d ^| findstr /v /i "\.bat$"|findstr /V /C:"APPENDTEXT"') do ren "%%a" "%%~na%var%%%~xa"`

Comment: @SamDenty I've [already got an answer from another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42458717/5040900). I was having problems with piping yet again. Thanks for your input. Much appreciated.