# Conditional rename inside for statement

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm looking for a solution that lets me rename all files, except **.bat** files, in the folder with a substring, *say* **APPENDTEXT**, appended at the end. [I've tried this before and it worked out great!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42209307/5040900) Now I'm at a loss on how to further improve it. I want it to recognize files that already have the substring inside the filename and skip renaming just those files.

> In all [my approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209307/escaping-symbol-used-in-findstr-within-a-for-statement?noredirect=1#comment71657479_42209652), I've failed and ended up appending nonce or double the substring.

A scenario would be some folder with mixed files such as:
EXAMPLEFOLDER
|---- file1.txt
|---- file2**APPENDTEXT**.txt
|---- file3**APPENDTEXT**.txt
|---- file4.txt
I want the files in this folder to be renamed something like this when I run the batch file:
EXAMPLEFOLDER
|---- file1**APPENDTEXT**.txt
|---- file2**APPENDTEXT**.txt
|---- file3**APPENDTEXT**.txt
|---- file4**APPENDTEXT**.txt

> Currently, they are being renamed like this(or none at all):
>   EXAMPLEFOLDER
>  |---- file1**APPENDTEXT**.txt
>  |----
>   file2**APPENDTEXTAPPENDTEXT**.txt
>  |----
>   file3**APPENDTEXTAPPENDTEXT**.txt
>  |----
>   file4**APPENDTEXT**.txt

Then I'm thinking of improving it further by exploring into all subfolders.
EXAMPLEFOLDER
|---- file1**APPENDTEXT**.txt
|---- file2**APPENDTEXT**.txt
|---- file3**APPENDTEXT**.txt
|---- file4**APPENDTEXT**.txt
|---- EXAMPLEFOLDER2
|---- |---- file21**APPENDTEXT**.txt
|---- |---- file22**APPENDTEXT**.txt

I've not done it yet because I still can't figure out how to stop renaming filenames that already contain the substring **APPENDTEXT**. It'd be great if the solution is built upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42209652/5040900). Can someone help me?

Comment: Pipe the DIR command to find or findstr and use the /V option.

Comment: You should change the title, it has nothing to do with formatting. --> exclude files from a dir list wihich already have an appended text. The links provided already show how to do it exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "var=APPENDTEXT"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.* /b /a-d ^| findstr /v /i "\.bat$" ') do (
   set "name=%%~Na"
   if "!name:%var%=!" equ "!name!" ren "%%a" "%%~na%var%%%~xa"
)
pause
```